# How do I search Microsoft's "Legal Stuff" displayed during PC setup?

Tags: windows-10, license

I purchased a laptop with Windows 10 for testing some libraries I contribute to. I'm at the Windows 10 *"Here's the Legal Stuff"* screen where Microsoft forces users into accepting their obscene terms by only providing an ***`Accept`*** button.

There are pages upon pages of stuff in this form, and I don't understand most of it. I want to search for some keywords in the agreement that I usually do [somewhat] understand, but I don't see how to search the form.

How do I search the "Legal Stuff" displayed during PC setup?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) to Windows 10 license terms.  You can search it through the browser.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer to search through the one Microsoft is forcing me to agree to, and not one that may (or may not) be the same. How can I determine if they are the same? How can I decline it (and avoid these troubles altogether)?